# Control object emission strength (not material)

Tags: node-editor, objects, shaders, emission

I have multiple objects with the same emission material. Is there a way to control the strength of the emission for each object?

Comment: Do you want to control the emission without having to dive into the shader editor ? Would a custom property in the scene do it ?

Comment: I don't think scene properties would work because I need different objects to have different amounts of emission, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Please edit your question and try to re-phrase it. It is not clear what you want.

Comment: are you saying that you want several objects to have the same emission material, but you want them to have different strength values?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest for me would be to use the object pass-index.

This is supposed to be used in the compositor workspace but the value can be accessed in the shader editor. It is an integer value so if you want more precision, you can add a math node set to divide between the "Object Info" node and the "Emission" node.

[image]