# What is the correct 'data_path' to animate the colour of a Principled BSDF node with Python?

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor

Version: 2.83

I want to change the colour of a material during animation - via python script.

I can create a cube wherever I want, called `myobject` and attached to it an appropriate material:

```
        material.use_nodes = True
        principled_bsdf = material.node_tree.nodes['Principled BSDF']
        principled_bsdf.inputs[0].default_value = colour
        principled_bsdf.inputs[5].default_value = 0
        myobject.active_material = material
```

I can then move the object for each `i` and use `myobject.keyframe_insert(data_path = "location", frame(i))` to insert frames appropriately. What is the correct `data_path` channel to insert keyframes for different colours, so I can change `principled_bsdf.inputs[0]` for whichever keyframes I want.

This question asks the same question, but doesn't have any answers: [Change the color via python script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159833/change-the-color-via-python-script)

Note that using `data_path = "color"` doesn't give an error, but also doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Keyframe the default value of the socket**

Animating by keyframe  the base colour of the bsdf node

To the python console.

From material "Material" get the bsdf node

```
>>> mat = D.materials['Material']
>>> bsdf = mat.node_tree.nodes['Principled BSDF']
```

What color is it now?

```
>>> bsdf.inputs['Base Color'].default_value
bpy.data.materials['Material'].node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value

>>> bsdf.inputs['Base Color'].default_value[:]
(0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929, 1.0)
```

Make it red and insert a keyframe at frame 30

```
>>> bsdf.inputs['Base Color'].default_value = (1, 0, 0, 1)
>>> bsdf.inputs['Base Color'].keyframe_insert("default_value", frame=30)
True
```

Same for blue at frame 50

```
>>> bsdf.inputs['Base Color'].default_value = (0,  0, 1, 1)
>>> bsdf.inputs['Base Color'].keyframe_insert("default_value", frame=50)
True
```

`True` above is indicating the success of adding the keyframe.  To keyframe a single channel (r, g, b, a) -> index 0, 1, 2, 3.  To keyframe just the green channel

```
input.keyframe_insert("default_value", index=1)
```

**One material.**

See this answer, https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/185314/15543

Could instead consider using one material and animate the object color.

```
ob.keyframe_insert("color", frame=33)
```

Comment: Thank you! This does the trick!