# Add rotation to a keyframe

Tags: python, keyframes

While I want to add rotation into a keyframe which is done using bpy.ops.transform.rotate, it either says no datapath called "rotation", or having no effects among keyframes.
What should I do if I want to do it?
The model is a rigged one and I want to rotate the bones which cannot use the rotation_euler.

Comment: Rotation is a vector property so I think you have to set the value on each axis, then add a keyframe similar to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/187405/add-rotation-to-a-key-frame

Comment: @Gorgious Thank you. I get what you mean. But the fact is that the object I want to choose is a bone from a whole model and it cannot be selected by bpy.data.objects, can only be selected objects.data.bones, which seems not having rotation_euler.